# Why does $P (Z=0)=\frac 1 2$ imply Z isn't normally distributed?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I understand [the Wikipedia proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normally_distributed_and_uncorrelated_does_not_imply_independent), except for the fact highlighted in green. 
$X+Y$ needs to be a normal distribution for the random variable to be normally distributed. But why does $P (X+Y=0)=\frac 1 2$ imply $X+Y$ isn't normally distributed?

[image]

Comment: Please link to the wikipedia proof. No reason not to.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews okay, I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any normally distributed random variable $Z:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ with variance $\sigma^2>0$ it holds that

$$\mathbb{P}(Z=x)=0 \qquad \text{for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$};$$

this follows directly from the fact that the (non-degenerate) normal distribution has a density with respect to the Lebesgue measure.

In the degenerate case, i.e. if the variance equals $0$, we have $\mathbb{P}(Z=x) \in \{0,1\}$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Consequently, there does not exist a normally distributed random variable $Z$ such that $\mathbb{P}(Z=0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I see... so the proof shows that the sum is not even a continuous random variable, therefore cannot be normal. Thanks!

Comment: @Whyka Yes, exactly. You are welcome.

Comment: Caveat: Dirac measures are often considered as normal distributions with variance zero (for very good reasons, for example to ensure that every linear combination of a normal family is itself normal, a convenient result which happens to be mentioned in the linked WP page). Hence, for every x and every normal Z, P(Z=x)=0 or P(Z=x)=1, but never .5, as desired.

Comment: @Did Yeah, sure, you're right...